# Saving a trained MultiLabelBinarizer on just unique labels of a dataset

Tags: scikit-learn

Hi I want to find out if there is a way to train `MultiLabelBinarizer` on just the number of classes available in a dataset and then load it when you want to make a transformation.

Lets say all the labels in my training set are as follows : `full_label_set = ["cat", "dog", "owl", "racoon", "hedgehog"]`

Then to train the and fit the classifier all I have to do is

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

full_label_set = ["cat", "dog", "owl", "racoon", "hedgehog"]
image1_labs = ["cat", "owl"]
mlb_encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes = full_label_set)
mlb_encoder.fit(img1_labs)
print(mlb_encoder.transform([image1_labs]))

>>>
[[1 0 1 0 0]]
```

But say now I want save this encoder using pickle and load to use it for some given image_labels which I don't know at the moment (I know all the labels in the entire dataset but not for a specific image).

```
mlb_encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes = full_label_set)
mlb_encoder.fit(full_label_set) # I dont know what to input here
pickle.dump(mlb_encoder, open("mlb_animal_encoder.pkl", "wb"))

mlb_encoder2 = pickle.load(open("mlb_animal_encoder.pkl", "rb"))
print(mlb_encoder2.transform([img1_labs]))

>>>
UserWarning: unknown class(es) ['Transitional woodland/shrub'] will be ignored
  warnings.warn(
[[0 0 0 0 0]]
```

When it comes the `LabelEncoder` this can be easily done ...

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
lab_encoder = LabelEncoder()
lab_encoder.fit(full_label_set)
pickle.dump(lab_encoder, open("lab_animal_encoder.pkl", "wb"))

lab_encoder2 = pickle.load(open("lab_animal_encoder.pkl", "rb"))
print(lab_encoder2.transform(image1_labs))
>>>
[0 3]
```

Any idea how I can do the same with `MultiLabelBinarizer`?